# Chrome Extension injecting iframe

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have my personal Google Chrome extension that adds an iframe to every page.
Now, it worked perfectly until a couple of days earlier.
Now it wont work on https pages!
The iframe source is HTTP.
The console is reporting: 
    [blocked] The page at https://example.com ran insecure content from http://mysite.com

Now, I know about mixed content issue, but it worked perfectly before. Why isnt it working now and how to fix it?
Anyone?

Thanks

Comment: Here they say explicitly that since v30 it won't be allowed: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=283781. And this is the change that caused that to happen: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238484

Comment: Thanks @rsanchez ! Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a new chrome update was released a couple of days ago. Check the patch notes from that release if they changed anything security related to make Chrome extensions require both HTTP or both HTTPS, not mixed.